# Injective but not surjective functions

Tags: functions

I'm trying to think of a function f: P -> P that it injective but not surjective. Where P is the set of even, non-negative integers {0,2,4...}.

I have the function f(x)=2x and know that it is injective for the function f: P->P, however i'm not sure of it's surjectivity. Could someone explain to me if this function would be surjective?

If it is surjective, could you show an example of an injective but not surjective function for f:P->P and explain the surjectivity part?

Comment: Given your function, can you solve $f(x)=2$?

Comment: No, so i guess that means the function is not surjective?

Comment: Well, "surjective" would require that every value in $P$ be a value of your function, so a single missed value is all you need.  As it happens your function only takes values which are multiples of $4$, so infinitely many values are missed.  You could also have considered something like $g(n)=n+2$ which only misses the value $0$.

Comment: Ok thanks, i wasn't sure if every single value in the set had to be included.

Answer (score 1):

The comment is completely correct!
There‘s no such element in the domain, that suffices $f(x)=2$. Hence the function is not surjective.
Actually, you can generalize that idea for every even number which is divisible by an odd number.

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$f(n)=2n,\quad (0,0),(2,4),(4,8),\dots$$

which never reaches values $2,6,10,\dots$ and therefore it is not surjective.